# How to get jobExecutionContext['key'] with class value key in xml file in spring batch

Tags: xml, spring, spring-batch

I can set `lastJobExecutionId` as `jobExecutionContext['_lastJobExecutionId']`. but the problem is `_lastJobExecutionId` is the value defined in another class. I don't want to use String '_lastJobExecutionId' in xml file and change it to reference of it (like `x.y.z.CustomTasklet.KEY_LAST_JOB_EXECUTION_ID`).

How do I fix it?

ASIS

```xml
    <bean id="reader" class="x.y.z.CustomReader" scope="step">
        <property name="sqlSessionTemplate" ref="SqlSessionTemplate"/>
        <property name="queryId" value="mybatis.mapper.x.y.z.selectTarget"/>
        <property name="pageSize" value="1000"/>
        <property name="lastJobExecutionId" value="#{jobExecutionContext['_lastJobExecutionId']}"/>
    </bean>
```

want TOBE like...

```xml
    <bean id="reader" class="x.y.z.CustomReader" scope="step">
        <property name="sqlSessionTemplate" ref="SqlSessionTemplate"/>
        <property name="queryId" value="mybatis.mapper.x.y.z.selectTarget"/>
        <property name="pageSize" value="1000"/>
        <property name="lastJobExecutionId" value="#{jobExecutionContext['x.y.z.CustomTasklet.KEY_LAST_JOB_EXECUTION_ID']}"/>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more about SpEL syntax, you can refer to a type using the following notation:

```
<property name="lastJobExecutionId" value="#{jobExecutionContext[T(x.y.z.CustomTasklet).KEY_LAST_JOB_EXECUTION_ID]}"/>
```

Please check the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions) for more details about the syntax.

Comment: the answer worked. thanks!! :)